# Does a GUI application invokes system calls to access the device driver?

Tags: user-interface, driver, system-calls

In non-GUI environment in Linux, a simple c program with a printf function actually invokes the kernel with 'write' system call when it has to write something on the display.

What happens in GUI environment in Linux? I can't believe so much of graphics is done through the system calls!

My guess is that a GUI application, during runtime, access the opengl library which access the GPU through the device driver without invoking any system call in the kernel. **Is it the case?** If not, could you please explain how a GUI application, on running, creates the graphics on screen?

Comment: What os are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

I just learnt that x-window access the I/O ports of the display device directly without using kernel's device driver. it uses iopl() and ioperm() system calls to seek the privilege to access I/O ports.
OpenGL has no direct access to the display device. it access it via device driver.

**x access the hardware directly.  OpenGL needs device drivers**